# Nativescript Vue this.$navigateTo does nothing

Tags: navigation, nativescript-vue

**EDIT: See my comment below about adding elements to Vue template**

**EDIT again today: Ok, so here is what actually causes `this.$navigateTo` to stop working...** If I import a service to make an http call out to a rest api in Friends.vue to get data in the mounted() event, this causes `this.$navigateTo` to stop working from the calling Home.vue. Can anyone suggest why?

This is in Friends.vue...

```
    mounted() {
    console.log(`${this.codeFile}: mounted() fired`);
    httpService.getAllFriends((data, err) => {
        this.friends = data;
        if (err) {
            console.error(
                `${this.codeFile}: mounted: getAllFriends: `,
                err
            );
        }
    });
},
```

I really feel like my code looks like the documentation, but my `this.$navigateTo(Friends)` does nothing. I can see the `console.log` message fine, but page does not change. What am I not seeing in the documentation?

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar class="action-bar" title="Home"></ActionBar>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout backgroundColor="#3c495e">
                <Label
                    text="Friends"
                    @tap="gotoFriendsPage()"
                    height="70"
                    backgroundColor="#43b883"
                />
                <Label text="Places" height="70" backgroundColor="#289062"/>
                <Label text="Messages" height="70" backgroundColor="#1c6b48"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
import Friends from "./Friends";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            codeFile: "Home.vue",
            friendsPage: Friends
        };
    },
    created() {
        //console.log(`${this.codeFile}: created() fired`);
    },
    mounted() {
        //console.log(`${this.codeFile}: mounted() fired`);
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {
        gotoFriendsPage: function() {
            console.log(`${this.codeFile}: gotoFriendsPage fired`);
            this.$navigateTo(Friends);
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
// Start custom common variables
@import "../_app-variables.scss";
// End custom common variables

// Custom styles
.action-bar {
    background-color: $blue-dark;
    color: $blue-light;
}
.body {
    color: gray;
}
.fa {
    color: $accent-dark;
    font-size: 16;
}
.col-text {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 3;
    padding: 5;
}
.col-title {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 5;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.info {
    font-size: 20;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT: Adding app.js**

```
    import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import Home from "./components/Home";

const template = `
    <Frame>
        <Home />
    </Frame>
`;

new Vue({
    template: template,
    components: {
        Home
    },
    mounted: function () {
        //console.log('app.js mounted fired...');
    },
    created: function () {
        //console.log('app.js created fired...');
    }
}).$start();
```

Comment: Maybe issue is in device or in compiling. I can't see anything strange here. Based on your code I created example here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vmbEXA and it works for me when checking with Playground app on Android

Comment: Hmmm you're right, that does work perfectly fine on my phone. So far I'm only testing on the emulator and can't get it working. I'll fiddle with this more later today. Thank you @jakob !

Comment: @jakob Yes this code does work locally. So what did I do wrong? Is it how I instantiated Vue in app.js? See reply below. I did that based on the demo/sample code, which is slightly diff from example you posted.

Comment: @jakob and anyone finding this later, jakobs simple example *does* indeed work in the playground *and* locally. The problem in OP, `this.$navigateTo` does nothing, happens when add more elements to the the target Friends.vue template. If you add other StackLayout or GridLayout or ListView or *anything* (it seems) to the target, `the this.$navigateTo` *STOPS* working. Why?

Comment: Can you create exact example like yours on nativescript play?

Comment: @jakob Yes I can. I'll do that when I get a break today. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @jakob, here you go: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=NnHdbs&v=8  This shows exactly what I'm experiencing. Notice that Friends.vue never load, yet you see the console.log in the method on each click. Now comment out just the RestAPI code and try again. Now navigateTo works again. What's happening?

Comment: @jakob, Ugh... I found it. Nice that the Nativescript-Vue just fails on this silently and shows no error during build or runtime. Notice the module.exports in http-service.js. Missing something?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Nativescript will silently fail on certain code errors. I've searched the build output and it does not catch the missing `module.exports`. Seems the build process should catch this. Right? The only way you see this issue is `this.$navigateTo` will silently fail if you have this code bug on the target page loading and calling the module. Super strange.

See the following NS Playground. Look in http-service.js. Notice that `module.exports` is missing the `getAllFriends` export. This is the invisible issue. Correct that `module.exports` and everything works fine.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=NnHdbs&v=8

I hope this helps someone later.

Answer (score 0):

How did you instantiate vue? Did you add the frame like this?

```
// Start
new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h("frame", [h(store.getters.isLoggedIn ? routes.Home : routes.Login)])
}).$start();
```

Comment: Thank you @Vince Lowe ! I edited the OP and added the app.js. This is how I had it when posting above. At the moment, I'm changing it up to see if I can get code *jakob* provided working locally. Do you see the issue in my original app.js above?

Comment: @Vince_Lowe See my comment about adding elements to target Friends.vue causes `this.$navigateTo` to stop working. Do you have any suggestion as to why this happens? I'm pretty stuck. Thank you! :-)